# Deleting rows in Pandas Dataframe, when column values match tuples in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
 index  col1  col2 col3
     0     1     3    5
     1    12     7   21
  ...    ...   ...  ...
```

I want to delete some rows, with the criteria being that the values in col1 and col2 show up in a certain list.
Let the list be `[(12,7),(100,34),...]`.
In this case, the row with index 1 would be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) for test `MultiIndex` created by both columns by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), invert mask by `~` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
L = [(12,7),(100,34)]

df = df[~df.set_index(['col1','col2']).index.isin(L)]
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
```